# copy struct to char pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, raw-sockets

I have the following Data Structure:

```
/*DNS Header Data Structure*/
struct dns_header {
    unsigned short id;
    unsigned short flags;
    unsigned short qdcount;
    unsigned short ancount;
    unsigned short nscount;
    unsigned short arcount;
};

/*DNS Packet Structure*/
typedef struct {
    struct dns_header dns;
    char data[0];
} packet_desc;
```

and I am using

```
packet_desc* pd;
```

to fill up the information. Now I want to send it as a payload of UDP RAW socket described [here](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-udp-sockets-c-linux/).

I need to copy the (pd) into a char pointer (similar to line 80 of the example code). How can I do that? I have tried different approaches explained in StackOverflow but they were mainly describing copying a data structure to a char array.

Comment: Commentary: I know a lot of old code uses `short`, `int`, etc. but I find the better way to go is `uint16_t`. And not only that, but typedef it and use `uint16be_t` for Big Endian. In C it can't be enforced, which makes C++ better because you can construct a C++ class that makes it impossible to get the BE and LE integers mixed up.

Comment: Although, actually, you can in C build it as `typedef struct { uint16_t value; } uint16be;` and only access it using inline getter and setter functions.

Comment: I think the example you linked to has everything you need, including the `memcpy` ...

Comment: Also "copying a data structure to a char array" is exactly what you need, because all that you can send to a network is bytes. AKA a char array.

Comment: I have used memcpy(data, pd->dns,12); and memcpy (data+12, pd->data, strlen(data); but I got funny errors.

Comment: isn't data defined as char * data in the example code? (line 64)

Comment: don't use `strlen(data)` for binary data. Did you allocate space for your destination buffer?

Comment: Funny errors need to be a lot more specific. I'm betting, completely at random, that your code is copying into `data` without allocating any memory for it. You have a `char data[0]` in that struct, which is a non-standard C extension supported by most compilers, but all that does is create a pointer offset for you at the end of the struct. You still have to malloc the space past the end.

Comment: I am using: data = datagram + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr);  and strcpy(data, pd); and I get 
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:108:1: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘packet_desc * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’
 __NTH (strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src))

Comment: should I use char * data in packet_desc;